# I wanted to know more about dma_map and dma_unmap

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-device-driver, dma

can somebody point me out to a simple doc on why dma_unmap is required. Please, be free to explain even the dma_map. I new to device drivers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following links can be useful:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access